# Read python properties file other package

Tags: python-2.7

How to read config.properties placed in separate package/directory using python 2.7 ?

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('ConfigFile.properties')

print config.get('default', 'test.name')
```

This of course works if config file is in same package, but if placed in different package - what is the best practice to read the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. variable `__file__` contains path to current python module file;
2. `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` yields parent directory name for python file;
3. if data file located inside python package, use function `pkgutil.get_data`.